# Mapped dropdown menu won't display frontmost

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, drop-down-menu

I just made a drop down menu for social medias in React. When I opened that drop down, it displays at back of every other component and I have a button to create another drop down menu at last of the col and when I opened another drop down above this closed drop downs, this drop downs won't stay at behind. I tried Z-index for it but it didnt't worked.

Turning input and drop down component

```
  let [socials, setSocials] = useState(
    props.user.data.social_medias || [
      { social_id: "Instagram" },
      { social_id: "Twitter" },
      { social_id: "Linkedin" },
    ]
  );

 <div id="web" className="w-full z-20">
    <p className="font-bold mb-4">Sosyal Medya</p>
    {
     socials.map((social,i) => (

       <Socials key={i} social={social} value={social.profile_url} />
    ))
    }
</div>
```

and my Socials Component

```
  let [socialType, setSocialType] = useState(props.social.social_id || "");
  let counter = 0;
  console.log("key" + props.key);
  let [value, setValue] = useState(props.value);
  const [showMenu, setShowMenu] = useState(false);

  const socialMedias = [
    { name: "Web Sitesi", img: web },
    { name: "LinkedIn", img: linkedIn },
    { name: "Instagram", img: instagram },
    { name: "Facebook", img: facebook },
    { name: "Twitter", img: twitter },
    { name: "Youtube", img: youtube },
  ];

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setValue(e.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <div
      name="social-inputs"
      key={props.key}
      className="flex flex-row h-10 w-full mb-4 "
    >
      <input
        className="inline-block w-1/2 outline-none rounded px-3"
        style={{ boxShadow: "1px 1px 5px rgba(0, 49, 108, 0.2)" }}
        value={value}
        onChange={(e) => handleChange(e)}
      />
      <ul
        className="text-center ml-4 w-1/2 bg-white py-2 rounded inline-block "
        style={{ boxShadow: "1px 1px 5px rgba(0, 49, 108, 0.2)" }}
      >
        <li
          onClick={() => setShowMenu(!showMenu)}
          className={
            showMenu
              ? " px-4 flex flex-row justify-between mb-1"
              : "px-4 flex flex-row justify-between  "
          }
        >
          <p className="truncate">
            <img
              src={
                (socialMedias.find(function (element) {
                  return element.name === socialType;
                }) &&
                  socialMedias.find(function (element) {
                    return element.name === socialType;
                  }).img) ||
                web
              }
              alt={
                (socialMedias.find(function (element) {
                  return element.name === socialType;
                }) &&
                  socialMedias.find(function (element) {
                    return element.name === socialType;
                  }).name) ||
                "Web"
              }
              className="mr-3 inline-block"
            />

            {(socialMedias.find(function (element) {
              return element.name === socialType;
            }) &&
              socialMedias.find(function (element) {
                return element.name === socialType;
              }).name) ||
              "Web"}
          </p>
          <img
            src={arrow}
            alt="arrow"
            className="flex justify-end items-center "
          />
        </li>
        <Medias
          showMenu={showMenu}
          setShowMenu={setShowMenu}
          setSocialType={setSocialType}
        />
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
```

and for map all values in drop down component is Medias

```
const Medias = (props) => {
  let { showMenu } = props;
  console.log(showMenu);
  const socialMedias = [
    { name: "Web Sitesi", img: web },
    { name: "LinkedIn", img: linkedIn },
    { name: "Instagram", img: instagram },
    { name: "Facebook", img: facebook },
    { name: "Twitter", img: twitter },
    { name: "Youtube", img: youtube },
  ];
  const mappedMedias = socialMedias.map((media, i) => {
    return (
      <li
        key={i}
        onClick={() => {
          props.setSocialType(media.name);
          props.setShowMenu(false);
        }}
        style={{ boxShadow: "1px 1px 5px rgba(0, 49, 108, 0.2)" }}
        className={
          showMenu
            ? "inline-block w-full bg-white px-3 py-3 linksBlue z-50 flex items-center"
            : "hidden"
        }
      >
        <img src={media.img} alt={media.name} className="mr-3" />
        {media.name}
      </li>
    );
  });

  return (
    <div className={showMenu ? "block z-50" : "hidden"}>{mappedMedias}</div>
  );
};
```

and lastly my images of problem are like this.
*None click*
[image: None click]
*When I click only the first drop down*
[image: When clicked first dropdown]

*When I click both first and second drop down*

[image: When I click both first and second drop down]

Answer (score 2):

From [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp)

`z-index` only works on positioned elements (position: absolute, position: relative, position: fixed, or position: sticky) and flex items (elements that are direct children of display:flex elements)

Add `flex` class or `position: relative` to your `<ul>` element add add `z-index` to your `<li>` elements greater than `<Socials>` component. It is hard to determine real issue without styles.

Answer (score 0):

you should take a look at parents.
If a side blind of your menus parent have a greater z-index the sons of it will be on top of your menus .
If your menus have a z-index of 1000 and their parent has a z-index of 1 an a side blind have a z-index of 2 its children will be on top of the menus

Comment: The container of the button have a greater z-index than the menus container

Comment: Thanks but already tried it. I'm not sure that it's about z-index, tried all variances about that.

Comment: But not the menu’s zindex, their parent. If you could share your styles I’ll help you

Comment: I just have inline stlyes and classnames in that code parts. I just handle the button, now drowdown front of it but still second dropdown header blocking the first one. I couldn't figure that out. I will add new pics now.

Answer (score 0):

If you add a `z-index` value to your dropdown menus, but it is the same for all of them, the latest ones will always be in top of the previous ones. So, let me suggest a different approach.

Try assigning an identifier class to `<li>` element of `Medias` component (e.g. `.media-option`).

Then, in the `onClick` value at `<li>` element of `Socials` component, use a function that hides all media menus before showing the one that have been clicked. Something like this:

```js
const onMenuClick = () => {
  const mediaOptions = document.querySelectorAll('.media-option')
  mediaOptions.map((mediaOption) => mediaOption.classList.add('hidden'))
  setShowMenu(!showMenu)
}
```

If that doesn't work, please share a full and working version of your code.